# Setting time zone in php

Tags: php, time

I'm using the following code to get server time. But I'm in Bangladesh and I don't get Bangladeshi time by this. Please tell me where I have to change for the exact Bangladeshi time.

```
$Vdate=date("F j, Y, g:i a");
```

Comment: [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/date-default-timezone-set)

Comment: This sounds more like a server configuration issue. You can take a look at your `php,ini` file...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Function [`date_default_timezone_set()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)<sup>>= 5.1.0</sup> set timezone globally.

If you need to set timezone locally, for specific variable, you can use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)<sup>>= 5.2.0</sup> and [DateTimezone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)<sup>>= 5.2.0</sup> classes, [like](https://eval.in/57712):

```
$dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimezone('Asia/Dhaka'));
echo $dt->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```

Here is the [list of all available timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) in PHP.

---

Since non of the above functions will work on PHP version 4.x, you have no other way to set timezone, rather that setting your server time to your timezone, or add offset to `time()` functions, like:

```
echo date('F j, Y, g:i a', time() - 6*3600); # Bangladesh is in UTC+6
```

Comment: But i'm facing this problem---->Fatal error: Cannot instantiate non-existent class: datetime in awa111.php

Comment: @MakReza: that can only mean you have php 4.x version. DateTime was added in version >= 5.2.0. I have updated my answer for version 4.x.

Answer (score 14):

You have to use:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

I'm not sure if this is the right timezone.

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka");
echo "The time is " . date("Y-m-d h:i:sa");
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. Why should one use the timezone of Dhaka?

Comment: Because geographical location.Here also use asia for geographical location.Dhaka is a capital of Bangladesh.

Answer (score 2):

I think the proper way to set your timezone is to set it in your php.ini configuration file.
You just have to set `date.timezone = "[Valid timezone value]"`.

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Himel Sarkar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
</head>
<body>



    <?php 
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
echo date("d-M-y h:i") ;

?>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you give an explanation of what is going on in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Check out `date_default_timezone_set()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Facing this message--->Fatal error: Call to undefined function: date_default_timezone_set()

Answer (score 0):

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Dhaka');
```

add this line before or set it in your `php.ini` file