# UTC datetime conversion to local datetime using PHP. How?

Tags: php, date, datetime

Using the following code I'm getting the output as mentioned below.

`echo $date = new date('c', strtotime('2017-03-14T22:30:00.000Z'));`

Current Output: `2017-03-15T04:30:00+06:00`

Expected Output: `2017-03-15 10:30:00 AM`

How could I do it using PHP?

Comment: Edit your php.ini file, then change / add following date.timezone directive: `date.timezone = "Asia/Dhaka"` then restart php service

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:
`echo $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s A', strtotime('2017-03-14T22:30:00.000Z'));`

Comment: This is working, but I also need to add +6 hours to adjust my local time and it will become `2017-03-15 10:30:00 AM `. My timezone is Asia/Dhaka. Can you please suggest me to make as I expected?

Comment: Please try this url for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19616822/how-to-set-my-time-zone-in-php

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use DateTime

```
$d = new DateTime('2017-03-14T22:30:00.000Z');
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
//2017-03-14 22:03:00

$d->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Dhaka'));
echo $d->format('Y-m-d H:m:s');
//2017-03-15 04:03:00
```

Also, it seems to me that Asia/Dhaka is in fact UTC+6 so what you are after would be `2017-03-15T04:30:00`, not `2017-03-15T10:30:00` (here the offset would be 12 hours)?